# Assigning to all entries whose indices sum to some value

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have an array `X` of binary numbers and shape `(2, 2, ..., 2)`, and would like to assign the value 1 to all entries whose indices sum to 0 modulo 2 and the value 0 to the rest.

For example, if we had `X.shape = (2, 2, 2)` then I would like to assign 1 to `X[0, 0, 0], X[0, 1, 1], X[1, 0, 1], X[1, 1, 0]` and 0 to the other 4 entries.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I assume I should create this array with the np.bool datatype, so the solution should work with that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a direct method and a tricksy one. The tricksy one uses bit packing and exploits certain repetitive patterns. For large `n` this gives a considerable speedup (`>50 @ n=19`).

```
import functools as ft
import numpy as np

def direct(n):
    I = np.arange(2, dtype='u1')
    return ft.reduce(np.bitwise_xor, np.ix_(I[::-1], *(n-1)*(I,)))

def smartish(n):
    assert n >= 6
    b = np.empty(1<<(n-3), 'u1')
    b[[0, 3, 5, 6]] = 0b10010110
    b[[1, 2, 4, 7]] = 0b01101001
    i = b.view('u8')
    jp = 1
    for j in range(0, n-7, 2):
        i[3*jp:4*jp] = i[:jp]
        i[jp:3*jp].reshape(2, -1)[...] = 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff ^ i[:jp]
        jp *= 4
    if n & 1:
        i[jp:] = 0xffff_ffff_ffff_ffff ^ i[:jp]
    return np.unpackbits(b).reshape(n*(2,))

from timeit import timeit

assert np.all(smartish(19) == direct(19))

print(f"direct   {timeit(lambda: direct(19), number=100)*10:.3f} ms")
print(f"smartish {timeit(lambda: smartish(19), number=100)*10:.3f} ms")
```

Sample run on a `2^19` box:

```
direct   5.408 ms
smartish 0.079 ms
```

Please note that these return `uint8` arrays, for example:

```
>>> direct(3)
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [1, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

But these can be view-cast to `bool` at virtually zero cost:

```
>>> direct(3).view('?')
array([[[ True, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False,  True],
        [ True, False]]])
```

Explainer:

direct method: One straight-forward way of checking bit  parity is to `xor` the bits together. We need to do this in a "reducing" way, i.e. we have to apply the binary operation `xor` to the first two operands, then to the result and the third operand, then to that result and the fourth operand and so forth. This is what `functools.reduce` does.

Also, we don't want to do this just once but on each point of a `2^n` grid. The `numpy` way of doing this are open grids. These can be generated from 1D axes using `np.ix_` or in simple cases using `np.ogrid`. Note that we flip the very first axis to account for the fact that we want inverted parity.

smartish method. We make two main optimizations. 1) `xor` is a bitwise operation meaning that it does "64-way parallel computation" for free if we pack our bits into a 64 bit uint. 2) If we flatten the 2^n hypercube then position n in the linear arrangement corresponds to cell (bit1, bit2, bit3, ...) in the hypercube where bit1, bit2 etc. is the binary representation (with leading zeros) of n. Now note that if we have computed the parities of positions 0 .. 0b11..11 = 2^k-1 then we can get the parities of 2^k..2^(k+1)-1 by simply copying and inverting the already computed parities. For example k = 2:

```
0b000, 0b001, 0b010, 0b011 would be what we have and
0b100, 0b101, 0b110, 0b111 would be what we need to compute
  ^      ^      ^      ^
```

Since these two sequences differ only in the marked bit it is clear that indeed their cross digit sums differ by one and the parities are inverted.

As an exercise work out what can be said in a similar vein about the next 2^k entries and the 2^k entries after those.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks! Could you add an explanation on how these work (at least the direct method)? Or more generally, how one comes up with such a solution?

Comment: @H.Rappeport I've added some explanations. HTH.